# How can I remove the file name from the path returned by FileDialog.FileName?

Tags: vb.net, file-io, file, .net

How can I remove the actual file name from the path returned by the `FileName` property of an Open or Save File Dialog?

All I want is the path to the file *without* the file name.

Comment: Look into the System.IO.Path class. If you just want the filename you can use System.IO.Path.GetFileName(saveFileDialog1.FileName) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.io.path.getfilename

Comment: Do you want the final output to the file name, or the *path* to the file *without* the file name?

Comment: I don't want the file name i just want the path

Comment: @Cody  The Second one, the path to the file without the file name

Comment: `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(saveFileDialog1.FileName)`   works

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Pass the full path (the one including the file name) to the **[`System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx)** method. This will strip out the file name and return the full path to the directory containing that file.

For example:

```
Dim filePath As String = "C:\MyDir\MySubDir\myfile.ext"
Dim directoryPath As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath)
```

Places the following string in the `directoryPath` variable:

> C:\MyDir\MySubDir

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim dir As String = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolderOption.None)
```

The value of `dir` will give you the path only.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted (I don't know vb, so maybe that is why) but it would be better for someone to explain why.

Answer (score -1):

My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(sFullFileName).DirectoryName

Comment: Can you provide more context?